Futuristic/dystopian novel for teens where people live in bubble-shaped/spherical houses
Years ago I read a dystopian/futuristic novel but I cannot find it anywhere and I don't remember much about it.

Main character: a boy, maybe a teenager;
Setting: dystopian world (maybe France, but I'm not sure about it) where society is split in 3+ classes/strata. People live in bubble-shaped/spherical houses.
Target: I think the target is for teens around 15 years old (I was around that age when I read it, around 10 years ago).

That's all I can remember. They're few hints, but maybe around the internet someone could recognize it.

Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE! Have a look at our helpful guide for asking story-id questions and if you happen to remember any extra details, please do [edit] them into your question. Was there a previous war or something forcing people to live in these weird houses? Do the houses differ depending on a person's class?
